# I learnt web-design in the late 90s/early 2000s. How do I get back into current web design style?

Tags: css, html

I know how to write html in the late 90s and early 2000s. It was past the geocities era, so my skills aren't that old/bad. I can write old-school html and css fairly well, but I've lost touch with the trends.

For example, if you told me to design a page from a photoshop mockup, I'd still start by using a table for layouts, and inserting things into cells, with colspan and rowspan. Menus I'd design would again be a subtable, instead of a ul with fancy css. And so on. Some of the stuff I see on new websites just blows my mind.

---

But whenever I try to look for resources to learn, I find two kinds:

1. The "HTML is for Everyone!" kind, which start teaching me how tags are
   things surrounded by angular brackets
2. The "How to use this amazing
   new css3/javascript library with hover, glow, and teleportation" kind.

Neither is suited for me really. I know, I might be a rather niche audience, but is there something out there for people like me? If not, can I just get some pointers thrown at me?

Preferably something that with a focus on elements of design (not syntax, not aesthetics)

(Do let me know if this is not the right forum for questions like this)

Comment: simple suggestion for starters...NEVER GO TO w3schools.com TO CATCHUP!!!

Comment: upvote for your question,honesty and the way of asking.

Comment: W3S is regular enough for beginners, but that's it.

Comment: Might belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. Still, being in your boat, coming from years of c++ video game programming before switching to web development, just pick something you're used to doing and do it in the web. For me, it meant making a 2D platform game by moving HTML elements like divs around. So pick a project you know how to code outside of the web, and hack around until you can do it in a browser, looking up topics as needed.

Comment: Apparently you're missing the basics of CSS then? Try starting here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: Not propably the best way, but the way I did the same: Choose a website to imitate. Start easy. And then think how you would do it "old-school" like : "I want this image to the left", and then check either css docs, or STACKOVERFLOW on how to achieve that. I've never been much of a reading books kinda guy.

Comment: You could also learn **photoshop** so that you can convert it into CSS. You may also start off by learning **javascript** or **jquery** ( a library of javascript).

Comment: @Mahe I'm actually fairly good with Photoshop. I'm not sure how I would go about converting Photoshop layouts to css though.

Comment: I started working as a graphic designer only a year ago, but had to school myself to be webdesigner as well. I learnt a lot from using web inspector (in Chrome). Just dug around code from other websites, gave me the best understanding.

Comment: There are lots of tools and plugins available online @user2175594. Just google for photoshop to css and you will find something suited for you. Incase you want to do it manually, try these 1.http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/convert-objects-to-css/  

2.http://designm.ag/resources/converting-psd-to-html/

Comment: @Mahe Oh my God! This looks amazing! Why are we bothering to write CSS any other way at all?!

Comment: Its mainly an individual's preference @user2175594 . Lazy guys like me go for tools. But, perfectionists do it own their own and there are lots of old school people out there like our questioner who use plain old fashioned css.

Comment: may this helps: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you mean with _The "HTML is for Everyone!" kind, which start teaching me how tags are things surrounded by angular brackets_.